# How to set eclipse preferences use plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Now I'm using python to change settings files under `.metadata/` in my workspace.I need find every line needed in these files beacuase I don't want any unnecessary content.

For example , if I want set tab's width be 4. I need change the file

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

in workspace and add a line following in it , not simply copy the settings file:

```
tabWidth=4
```

**So I want to know** : Can I set this value by java code in eclipse plugin? If it can, please give me related classes :-)

**And**, does it more complex than python's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a plugin you can use:

```java
IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "org.eclipse.ui.editors");

store.setValue("tabWidth", 4);
```